# Error when executing SQL Query on remote Database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm connected to a remote database through the university and have the following code for what seems to be a simple query. Can't figure out why I receive this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'USA'.
```

If this is the same database we have previously downloaded and performed local queries the column it should work smoothly. My code through Sequel Management Studio is:

```
SELECT Customers.CompanyName, Customers.ContactName, Customers.Country
FROM Customers
WHERE (Customers.Country="Mexico") OR (Customers.Country="USA") OR (Customers.Country="Canada")
```

Comment: Just use single quotes for country values.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong quotes in your query, use `'` instead of `"`:

```
SELECT Customers.CompanyName, Customers.ContactName, Customers.Country
FROM Customers
WHERE (Customers.Country='Mexico') 
  OR (Customers.Country='USA') 
  OR (Customers.Country='Canada')
```

Comment: I caught that after I submitted but that didn't help. There has to be a problem with the database on the server. While in management console the query design editor does not display any tables or columns. Starting to believe my code is good and the issue is the professor and dbase.

Comment: Sorry, ended up being a permissions problem. I knew my code was correct as simple as it is. Appreciate the help though.